# What champion monster enchantments pass to their minions?

Tags: diablo-iii

Champion monsters are often surrounded by minions.  In some cases, I've seen these minions inherit the magical properties of their masters, but this is not always the case.  For instance, sometimes minions of a nightmarish monster are also nightmarish.

What causes a minion to inherit the master's abilities?  Does it always happen for certain abilities, but not for others?  What about when multiple abilities are available on the unique monster?  Are all inherited by the minions, or is there a cap?

Comment: By 'unique' I hope you mean 'champion' - as 'uniques' are named mobs that have a constant or random spawn, and 'champions' are surrounded by minions which are always random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not random.

List:

- Plague
- Arcane Enchanted
- Mortar
- Molten
- Electrified
- Fast
- Extra Health
- Knockback
- Nightmarish
- Teleporter
- Vampiric

Comment: technically invulnerable minions adds an effect to the minion as well

Comment: Yes technically it propogates an effect but the base effect itself does not propogate. Technically speaking of course.

Answer (score -3):

It is random whether a minion inherits the elite/unique monster's abilities, but the chance is very high. There are some abilities for elite/unique monsters that specifically apply to minions as well, such as "indestructible minions." Yes, you read that right.